# Error: An application has been forced to stop for an unauthorized attempt to access system in your device.

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3, force-stop

I am getting the following error message every now and then. As far as I notice, it only happens if my phone has internet connection mostly on Wifi.

```
an application has been forced to stop for an unauthorized attempt to access system in your device. it may be    safe to delete an application obtained from an unauthorized route. Check now?
```

When i click Check Now it just shows me list of all apps but don't tell me which is having problem. It is Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and it is not rooted or i don't remember i installed any application which is not from Play store.

I googled and researched and found other people is getting same problem but i don't see any way to solve it. Anyone here knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it appears, long press on the message and it shows the app causing the problem. (It probably is Knox.) Clear data and clear cache, that worked for me.

Comment: it is indeed Knox. I have cleared data and cache. hope the message won't come back. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Wen, it doesn't actually work !!!! I mean it seems to work for a while  but it comes back now. Now I understand Knox is only the app giving me notification and it is not the actual program that is causing this problem. There must be a program trying to get unauthorized access but i can't think of anything.

Answer (score -1):

My friend has a note 3 with the same problem. We found a solution here:

http://www.droidviews.com/disable-knox-security-service-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/